My React Native app crashes (a simple mistake)
Before the SDK 51 update came to Expo, my application was working, but now when I navigate between tabs or click a button with a navigator, the application closes, probably due to a simple error. What is the reason and how can I solve it?
I tried:
watchman watch-del '/Users/ege'

then:
watchman watch-project '/Users/ege'


Do you have any logs you can post here? Any crash logs?

@DanGerchcovich Here is the log:
opendir(/Users/ege/Library/Containers/com.apple.corerecents.recentsd/Data/Library/Recents) -> Operation not permitted. Marking this portion of the tree deleted To clear this warning, run: watchman watch-del '/Users/ege' ; watchman watch-project '/Users/ege'`
opendir(/Users/ege/Library/Containers/com.apple.corerecents.recentsd/Data/Library/Recents) -> Operation not permitted. Marking this portion of the tree deleted
To clear this warning, run:
`watchman watch-del '/Users/ege' ; watchman watch-project '/Users/ege'``

It is a fresh issue of expo sdk 51.
You simply need to install reanimated library.

npx expo install react-native-reanimated

Then import it from top of your root layout file. (_layout.tsx)

import "react-native-reanimated"

More info at:
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/28618
